# How to install phonegap-2.7.0 for ios?

Tags: ios, cordova, installation

I have downloaded the phonegap-2.7.0 from http://phonegap.com/,but i don't know how to install it,(There is a Makefile,but nothing happened when execute the "make" command in the terminal,i have already quit the xcode),would anyone help me?

Comment: Look in: /phonegap-2.7.0/lib/ios/bin/   There should be a create file in that directory.  Then follow the instructions on the "Getting Started" site as you normally would.

Comment: That doesn't make it available as a project type in XCode.

Answer (score 4):

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html

These instructions are pretty clear, even if the directory tree you get after extracting the zip file is not exactly the one they show.

After installing all the requirements:

- extract the content of phonegap-2.7.0.zip wherever you want
- go to lib/ios/bin and run the 'create' command with the suggested parameters.
- open the finder and go to the directory you used as first parameter of the 'create' command
- doubleclick the file with extension xcodeproj to open XCode and the project will be automatically created

To open the finder in the right folder you can use the command line:

```
open ~/workspace/yourProject
```

or

```
cd ~/workspace/yourProject
open `pwd`
```

my 2c